# Redux: for loops worked in a reducer but filter didn't

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux and I came across this problem when using `import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"`

The goal was to remove some objects inside an array that has `listId === action.payload.id`

This (1) works:

```
    todosRemoved: (todos, action) => {
      for (let i = todos.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (todos[i].listId === action.payload.id) {
          todos.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
```

but this (2) didn't:

```
    todosRemoved: (todos, action) => {
      todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id)
    }
```

I'd prefer to use the (2) but I don't know what I did wrong there. I really appreciate if someone could elaborate it. Thanks!

Comment: Just add the return to filter and it should work.

Comment: @HassanImam for ES6 arrow functions, you can't  use the `return` keyword if you aren't using the `{ }` syntax. And when `{ }` is not used, arrow functions do an implicit return.

Comment: @HassanImam Oh man thank you so much, I've been spending like 6 hours trying to find the answer... Could you post it as an answer so that I can mark it please? I appreciate it!

Comment: @Link it did work and I don't know why tbh.

Comment: Can you show us your new code? It will work if you add a `return` keyword here 
`todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id)` The reason is basically instead of storing the value of the filter return result into a new array, you are directly returning it instead of returning the new array variable. You're still returning a new array.

Comment: @Link I am aware that arrow function without curly braces implicitly return but here code has curly braces, adding `return` statement made sense. If OP removes curly braces then we can skip adding return.

Comment: @HassanImam I thought you were asking OP to add the return statement inside the filter, my bad `:D`

Comment: @Link No problem, yeah it could be interpreted that way as well. I am glad my suggestion solved OP problem.

Comment: @Link This works perfect: `todosRemoved: (todos, action) => {
return todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id);` }

Comment: @Tui this works because you `Array.prototype.filter( )` returns a new array, and instead of capturing that array in a variable and returning it out, you are returning the result directly, it's one and the same thing. The takeaway here is that `filter( )` returns a new array instead of mutating the original array.

Comment: @Link MAN! I understand it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id)
```

this line is returning your valid objects of array, not updating your actual array. All you have to do is to save these all object in dummy array like this

```
case SET_TODO:
let dummyArray = todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id);
console.log(dummyArray) 
return Object.assign({}, state, {
             todo: dummyArray
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Sanoodia! I tested this one but somehow it didn't clear the `state.todo`, only the UI. So let me try some more time. I appreciate it!

Comment: I edited my solution plz have a look again. May be now its gonna help you now

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.filter( )` does not mutate the original array, it instead returns a new array with the values satisfying the filter condition:

**So what you need to do is:**

```
todosRemoved: (todos, action) => {
      const newTodos = todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id)
      console.log(newTodos); //this will have the expected values
    }
```

**Try running the below snippet example if you want to see an example:**

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];

const arr1 = arr.filter(el => el % 2 === 0);

console.log('This is the original array (Still Intact):', arr);
console.log('This is the new array:', arr1);
```

Comment: Thanks Link! I tested your code but somehow it didn't clear the objects in the `state.todos`. It did clear my UI though. So I don't really understand. I'll try more with it. Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: If you want to clear the todos in your state, you need to do something like this in your reducer function : `return {...sate, todos: todos}` where `todos` is your todos array which the filter will return. Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Link!

Answer (score 1):

Just return the filtered array.

```
todosRemoved: (todos, action) => {
      return todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id) 
}
```

or even better like..

```
todosRemoved: (todos, action) => todos.filter((todo) => todo.listId !== action.payload.id)
```

Comment: Thanks man! The first one worked perfect but the second one I got this `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`.

Comment: Ahh I see, i guess its because actions need to be functions. But ideally its also a function. not sure though why this error. But anyways glad that first one worked for you.